# symfony2 get all validation constraints on an entity (yml, xml, annotations)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Im trying to get all validation constraints on an entity and translate theses constraints to Jquery validation rules, right now im able to get annotation defined constraints (thanks to : [Symfony2 get validation constraints on an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482725/symfony2-get-validation-constraints-on-an-entity)), but im having some trouble getting xml and yml ones.

```
$xml_file_loader = new XmlFileLoader("path_to_my_project/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\validation.xml");
```

Using a similar code means that i need to know beforehand where the xml/yml file is located, i m trying to write somehow a generic code that can do this automatically.

Isn't there a way to get all constraints at once? if not how can i know the location of xml/yml files, and also in cases of inheritance i need to check for parent constraints... Is this doable?

Comment: You can use for this reasons - https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYJsFormValidationBundle.

Comment: i already tried that, it only gets annotation constraints...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private function getValidations()
    {
        $validations=[];
        $validator=$this->get("validator");
        $metadata=$validator->getMetadataFor(new your_entity());
        $constrainedProperties=$metadata->getConstrainedProperties();
        foreach($constrainedProperties as $constrainedProperty)
        {
            $propertyMetadata=$metadata->getPropertyMetadata($constrainedProperty);
            $constraints=$propertyMetadata[0]->constraints;
            $outputConstraintsCollection=[];
            foreach($constraints as $constraint)
            {
                $class = new \ReflectionObject($constraint);
                $constraintName=$class->getShortName();
                $constraintParameter=null;
                switch ($constraintName) 
                {
                    case "NotBlank":
                        $param="notBlank";
                        break;
                    case "Type":
                        $param=$constraint->type;
                        break;
                    case "Length":
                        $param=$constraint->max;
                        break;
                }
                $outputConstraintsCollection[$constraintName]=$param;
            }
            $validations[$constrainedProperty]=$outputConstraintsCollection;
        }
        return $validations;
    }
```

**Returns:**

```
array(13) (
      [property1] => array(4) (
        [NotBlank] => (string) notBlank
        [NotNull] => (string) notBlank
        [Type] => (string) string
        [Length] => (int) 11
      )
      [property2] => array(4) (
        [NotBlank] => (string) notBlank
        [NotNull] => (string) notBlank
        [Type] => (string) string
        [Length] => (int) 40
      )
      ..........
)
```

**The returned array can be configured or used to define client side validation rules depending on the client-side validation library/code that you are using**

```
$validator=$this->get("validator");
$metadata=$validator->getMetadataFor(new yourentity());
```

The object `$metadata` now contains all the metadata about validations that concerns your specific entity.

Comment: I'm adding a question to this (I know it was a long time ago). I've followed your script and it goes well. But in my constraint.yml I used the {{ limit }} in my messages and this keyword is not resolved by symfony when I use your script. You have a way around ?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't care about parent constraints .