# Output an entity constraints in form with message in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity which have these fields.

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
  /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=64)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="First name cannot be blank")
   * @Assert\Length(max=64, maxMessage="First name cannot more than {{ limit }} characters long")
   */ 
   private $firstName;

   .....

}
```

Now I would like to output these constraints in form somewhat like this.

```
<input type="text" required="required" data-required-msg="First name cannot be blank" name="firstname" data-max-length="64" data-max-length-msg="First name cannot be more than 64 characters long">
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this in Symfony 2 without manually creating these messages and data attributes in form again.

Comment: Seems like you want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573935/symfony2-get-all-validation-constraints-on-an-entity-yml-xml-annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using following code snippet.

Here I am injecting a validator service to read a metadata(annotation) of a class. In our case `User` class. Then on `prepareConstraints` function iterating through each property constraints and adding them to an array whose `key` is property name. Then on `buildForm` function adding constraints as a field `attr` values.

**On your constroller**

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType($this->get('validator'),$this->get('translator')), $user);
```

**On your** `UserType` class:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    private $metaData;
    private $constraintMessages;
    private $translator;

public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validatorInterface,TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $this->metaData = $validatorInterface->getMetadataFor('AppBundle\Entity\User');
    $this->translator = $translator;
    $this->prepareConstraints();
}

private function prepareConstraints()
{

    foreach ($this->metaData->properties as $property) {
        foreach ($property->constraints as $constraint) {
            $class = get_class($constraint);
            $constraintName = substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1, strlen($class));
$message = property_exists($class, 'message') ? $constraint->message : $constraint->maxMessage;;
            $this->constraintMessages[$property->name]['data-'.$constraintName] = $this->translator->trans($message,array('{{limit}}'=>...))
        }
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'name',
            null,
            array(
                'label' => 'label.name',
                'attr'  => $this->constraintMessages['name'],
            )
        )
        ...
}
```

}

**Result**

```
<input type="text" id="app_user_name" name="app_user[name]" required="required" data-notblank="This value should not be blank." class="form-control" value="">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But your solution only solves half of the problem. It does not format the messages nor it translates it. If you look closely message have place holder {{ limit }} that needs to be filled in.

Comment: Now its solves, you can tune the translator service however you want,